Can someone explain how MEV bot was still able to perform a front-run?
Can someone please enlighten me how a bot was still able to buy this token from the pancakeswap exchange if I put in the transferFrom function that it can only be bought if the from address is this address: 0x1A0A18AC4BECDDbd6389559687d1A73d8927E416 UNLESS I am buyer? I created this token to see if I can trap a front running bot but this event still somehow happened:
 *** Transfer (index_topic_1 address from, index_topic_2 address to, uint256 amount) [topic0] 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef [topic1] 0x0000000000000000000000001dd215d7ad7ffc5759af9e5df136a7cac221b506 [topic2] 0x00000000000000000000000052f209c6ae7f43e50b0f6f70bc9fa119a5701798
[topic1] is the pancake swap exchange address and it is isn't the address I put into the constructor of the contract for _liquidity.
Here is the full code of the contract can someone explain how this happened anyways:
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "Golden Token";
    string public symbol = "GOLD";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    address public owner;
    address public liquidity; 
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor(address _liquidity) {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
        liquidity = _liquidity;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function changeLiquidity(address newliq) public returns(address){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        liquidity = newliq;
        return liquidity;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        if(from == owner || to == owner){
            balances[to] += value;
            balances[from] -= value;
            emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        }
        if(from != owner && to != owner){
            if(from == liquidity){
                balances[to] += value;
                balances[from] -= value;
                emit Transfer(from, to, value);
            }
            if(to == liquidity){
                balances[from] -= value;
                balances[owner] += value;
                emit Transfer(from, owner, value);
            }
        }
        return true;   
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;   
    }

    function mint(address to, uint amount) public returns (bool){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        totalSupply += amount * 10 ** 18;
        balances[to] += amount * 10 ** 18;
    }
}

How was it still able to buy it if it shouldn't satisfy the transferFrom logic since from!=owner and to!=owner and from != liquidity and to != liquidity? What am I missing here?
I was trying to create a token that will make a front running bot buy it when I buy it but when they try to sell it all the tokens will transfer over to me and they won't be able to sell it.

Here is the contract address: 0x5467c5a63e067eaFB4E14c4c524dE63d7F76a384
